# SparkSession Connect to Databricks Azure

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I'm using maven and scala to create a spark application that needs to connect to a cluster on azure databricks. 
How can i point my sparksession to connect to the databricks cluster?

I saw *databricks-connect*, but it loads some jar files using sbt.
I don't understand how it achives that connectivity exactly.

My use case requires to run a spark job programmatically on the db cluster upon request, so i need to be able to connect it there.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, from where are you trying to run this spark job? From another application, adf or where?

Comment: For now i'm trying to run it through my IntelliJ.. but later this app will need to be deployed as a Docker and make requests to the cluster. using the databricks-connect and sbt as the guide says i managed to run the code on the cluster. Now i use maven, i import the jars and even though i manage to submit my jars it cant find some classes, even though i have uploaded them on the cluster as a jar.
What i basically want to do is make my sparksession connect to the databricks cluster @partha_devArch

Comment: First try one simple thing - build the jar, and try to run in directly within databricks as a spark job. Please see if that works. That will ease you to streamline the db-connect issue.